# Tomcat WebApp deployed but not accessible

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I have a strange problem with accessing Tomcat WebApps. I have several WebApplications all working fine on my development machine. But when I deploy them to the test server (copying to webapp folder) some of them can't be accessed, one of them being the tomcat manager app.

Edit1: The tomcat webapp folder is not the default, but (from server.xml):

```
<AutoWebApp dir="E:/daten/web/my.pma.de/servlet" host="DEFAULT" />
```

The tomcat log says

```
INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory E:\daten\web\my.pma.de\servlet\manager
Jun 26, 2016 5:02:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 26, 2016 5:02:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deployment of web application directory E:\daten\web\my.pma.de\servlet\manager has finished in 109 ms
```

But when I try to access the manager app (which again is working fine on my development machine) I always get a 404 error:

```
The requested URL /manager was not found on this server.
```

tomcat-users.xml contains correct credentials for the manager webapp:

```
<tomcat-users>
<user password="xxxxx" roles="manager-script,manager-gui,admin, admin-gui" username="xxxxx"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance
Jens

Comment: you should be able to access manager app with default tomcat installation provided admin credential needs to be configured in tomcat-users.xml.

Comment: If you copied to `webapp` folder, why is that name not in the shown path (`E:\daten\web\my.pma.de\servlet\manager`)?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that on the test server (contrary to my development machine) the Tomcat server was running "behind" a mod-jk in Apachte httpd. So basically what was lacking was mounting the webapps with "JkMount".

Edit:
As per request the mounting of the WebApp:
In httpd.conf

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile "conf/worker.properties"
JkLogFile "logs/mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel errorJ
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat
```

In httpd-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
.
.
.
    JkMount /mywebapp/* mainworker
    
    # Zugang zu WEB-INF und META-INF sperren
    <Location "/mywebapp/META-INF/*">
      #AllowOverride None
      deny from all 
    </Location>     
.
.
.
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of how to mount a webapp with "JkMount"?

Comment: @philburns See next answer :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, yes that shines a light. It would be better though to edit the original answer, hence, to amend the content of the second answer to your first one. This will be less confusing to others then. Also, better leave the personal note out of the answer. You can delete the second answer, after you have copied the relevant content. I will be happy to upvote your answer then.